# How to bind touch events on ajax-added elements

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm using the [touchSwipe jQuery Plugin](https://github.com/mattbryson/TouchSwipe-Jquery-Plugin) for a little WebApp.
Unfortunately, it doesn't work with dynamically added elements (e.g. via AJAX).

Well, i looked through the code and found something like:

```
$element.bind(START_EV, touchStart);
$element.bind(CANCEL_EV, touchCancel);
```

How can i bind the events so that they are available for dynamically added elements too?

Comment: what about .live()? Did you tried it?

Comment: `.live()` is deprecated and should be replaced with `.on()`, but `.on()` doesn't work in this way with this plugin.

Answer (score 1):

Use `on` and delegated events:

```
$(document).on('event', 'element_selector', function(){
    // do when event happens
});
```

But for that plugin you *might* have to attach the events to the new objects as they are added to the page.

Comment: Yep, i tried on() already, but it doesn't work, cause all elements (i use the plugin for many `li` elements) will be triggered when the app starts.

Comment: @Slevin why will they be 'triggered'? This just delegates the event, it does **not** trigger it.

Comment: Sorry, wrong wording. The function, which shall be called when the user interacts with ONE of the list elements, fires for each list element when using this code: `$(document).on(START_EV, $element, touchStart);`

Answer (score 0):

More details on using `.on` for this scenario, as shown in an [example in this post](https://eureka.ykyuen.info/2013/12/11/touchswipe-implement-delegated-swipe-event-for-inner-elements/):

```js
$("#boxes").on('mouseover','.box', function() {
    $(this).trigger('swiping');
});

$("#boxes").on('swiping','.box', function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.swipe({
        swipe: function(event, direction, distance, duration, fingerCount) {
            $this.text("You swiped " + direction );
        }
});
```

In the code snippet above, new `.box` elements are created dynamically. You create a `'swiping'` event and trigger it on hover for `.box` elements (including new ones added through AJAX, etc.). The second part then watches for the `'swiping'` event and attaches the plugin's `.swipe()` catchall for the `.box` element.